# Script executes but code-behind not

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a button on my aspx page. With this button, I'll add a option element into a select element and add some data to a GridView displayed on the page. I want to put the option element first than executes my code-behind from  this button.

I have the button and the evaluated combobox:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="comboboxPeople" ... />
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="comboboxOutput" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="buttonAdd" text="Add passanger" OnClick="buttonAdd_Click" OnClientClick="addOptionToSelectElement();" />
```

I have the script:

```
function addOptionToSelectElement() {
    var cb = document.getElementById('<%=comboboxPeople.ClientID %>');
    var cbout = document.getElementById('<%=comboboxOutput.ClientID %>');
    var op = document.createElement("op");
    op.value = cb.options[cb.selectedIndex].value;
    op.text = cb.options[cb.selectedIndex].text;
    cbout.appendChild(op);
}
```

And my code-behind:

```
protected void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoSomething(...);
}
```

Here's my problem: If I attach the script function to my button, the code-behind doesn't work. If I don't use the script, my code-behind runs.

Any idea?
Thanks!!

Comment: Does the JS behave as intended? I haven't tried it myself (so I'm not sure if it is valid), but it seems the element you want to create is `option`, while you are creating `op`. Also, what if you add `return true;` at the end of `addOptionToSelectElement()`, and use `OnClientClick="return addOptionToSelectElement();"`?

Answer (score 1):

where does comboboxOutput comes from. I tired without below lines and it worked

```
var cbout = document.getElementById('<%=comboboxOutput.ClientID %>');


cbout.appendChild(op);
```

Comment: Thanks, Mehmet, but I don't understand your solution!

Comment: you didnt write comboboxOutput where is it in your sample code abow? It gives me an error and ı deleted it :)

Comment: Ah, sorry. This dropdown exists. I forgot to put it into HTML code.

Comment: <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="comboboxOutput" />

Comment: dont use appendChild.. use cbout.options.add(op)

Comment: and ı used comboboxOutput is a html select element. so it works fine